# Find available memory after address returned by malloc

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

So I wrote this (Actually trying to see if realloc was O(n)-ish or not):

```
int main() {
time_t t1,t2;
char* x=malloc(sizeof(char));
char* y=x;
printf("%p %p\n",(void*)x,(void*)y);
double tot_time=0.0;
double time_r=0.0;
size_t s=2;
for(;;s++) {
    t1=clock();
    x=realloc(x,s*sizeof(char));
    t2=clock();
    if(x!=y) break;
    time_r=difftime(t2,t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    //printf("%p %p %zu %f secs\n",(void*)x,(void*)y,s,time_r);
    tot_time+=time_r;
}

printf("%zu elements %f secs\n",s,tot_time);
return 0;}
```

Which reallocs with a constantly incrementing size (by 1 byte) the memory returned by malloc at the beggining until a different address is returned. When such thing happens, it will tell you how much memory was possible to alloc after that initial address returned by malloc.

My question is: On a machine running Linux (In my case Ubuntu 14.04 64bits) is there any way to know before hand how much can the memory pointed to by x expand?

Comment: This is implementation-dependent.  You could read the source code for the version of `malloc` you're using, or even write your own (or make a private copy of some standard version), but other than that, there are no guarantees.

Comment: And try to find about the size of the memory block my address belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

This is really tricky. Have a look at the code below. In particular I'm using
malloc_usable_size to display what actually was allocated last time realloc was called.

This also does not factor in any effects that an application might have ie some
apps will allocate blocks in certain ranges more than others and depending on
the implementation of realloc this can have a large impact on performance.

Realloc in most cases is not copying data ie it's not being forced to be at least O(n) it's normally adjusting a pointer. When it does have to copy data then it's at best O(n) but this will be determined by the application.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  time_t t1;
  time_t t2;
  double tot_time = 0.0;
  double time_r   = 0.0;
  size_t s        = 2;

  char *x = malloc(sizeof(char));
  char *y = x;

  printf("%p %p\n",(void*)x,(void*)y);

  for(;;s++) {
    t1 = clock();
    printf("s=%zu  usable=%zu\n", s, malloc_usable_size(x));
    x  = realloc(x, s * sizeof(char));
    assert(x != NULL);
    t2 = clock();
    if( x != y) {
      break;
    }
    time_r = difftime(t2, t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    //printf("%p %p %zu %f secs\n",(void*)x,(void*)y,s,time_r);
    tot_time += time_r;
  }
  printf("%zu elements %f secs\n", s, tot_time);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

malloc_usable_size() return the no of usable bytes that can be allocated to the pointer

Comment: I don't think that is correct, since if i printf it after allocating memory to x it says "24" and i can realloc up to 135000 bytes more to it.

Comment: realloc copies the data in another block if there is not enough space available in the same block

Comment: I know that, but in my code, the for breaks when such thing happens. So i know it wasn't copied to another block before that, the block just expanded. malloc_usable_size() returns the usable memory allocated to a pointer, not how much can be allocated to a pointer, which is what i was asking for. Thanks, though!